# Combobox values from a textfile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, text-files, vb.net-2010

Hope people can help!

I'm attempting to create a combobox filled with information from a text file thats been delimited using , as a break mark. IE

objecta,grad,N,words,5,moretext

I need the various areas between the , as integers/booleans/strings .. but I'm having problems getting the code to do this properly working

Ive searched the web, and found this code, but its not working properly for me. Maybe Im being dumb but hopefully someone can help me. Help me oh gurus of the internet!

```
Public Sub meritlist()
    Dim looksups As New ArrayList
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim rdr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(c:merits.txt")
    While Not rdr.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = rdr.ReadLine()

        'Split the line by a comma:
        Dim arrayList = line.Split(",")

        'Get the right values: break down is as: Merit Name,Type,Shared,Carthan,Max,Pre-Req
        Dim meritname As Integer = arrayList(0)
        Dim merittype As String = arrayList(1)
        Dim meritshared As Boolean = arrayList(2)
        Dim carthan As String = arrayList(3)
        Dim meritmax As Integer = arrayList(4)
        Dim prereq As String = arrayList(5)

        cmoMRDro.Items.Add(New lookups(arrayList(0), arrayList(1)))

    End While
    rdr.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: 1.) File Path is incorrect. Is that a typo? 2.) `objecta,grad,N` do not fall under the `integers/booleans/string`. For ex `words,5,moretext` fall under the category string/Integer/string`

Comment: 1) changed to make it fit on the page, but it is correct yes. 2) YEah I kinda mashed together an example to show how it would look .. The meritname, merittype, carthan, and prereq were all strings. I realise now I put the shared in as a N rather than a false option by accident.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 things I would suggest.

1. Use `TextFieldParser` class to read delimited/fixed width text files. They are more specialized in doing this job and already have the code to handle it properly.
2. The call to `InitializeComponent` is not required.
3. Create a structure/class to store your line items, instead of raw variables. This way you have it in a more organized way.
4. Use `List` of that structure/class, instead of `ArrayList`

While what you are already doing can be corrected with a few modifications, I would have done it this way, keeping all the suggestions I gave above. So you can see how easy it becomes after this:

```
Structure MeritListType
    Dim meritname As Integer
    Dim merittype As String
    Dim meritshared As Boolean
    Dim carthan As String
    Dim meritmax As Integer
    Dim prereq As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal data() As String)
        meritname = Integer.Parse(data(0))
        merittype = data(1)
        meritshared = Boolean.Parse(data(2))
        carthan = data(3)
        meritmax = Integer.Parse(data(4))
        prereq = data(5)
    End Sub
End Structure

Public Sub MeritList()
    Dim FileData As New List(Of MeritListType)
    Dim tfp As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\merits.txt")
    tfp.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    tfp.SetDelimiters(",")
    While Not tfp.EndOfData
        FileData.Add(New MeritListType(tfp.ReadFields))
    End While
    tfp.Close()

    '' you have the records in FileData
    '' do whaever you want to do with it here now

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For the TextFieldParser suggestion. I absolutely agree with you on that.

Comment: attempted to use this, but it comes with an error on the filedata.add(new meritlistype(ftp.readfields)) .. says it has no constructors ..

Comment: I think you forgot to put `Public Sub New(ByVal data() As String)` in your structure. You would need to put that. And you would also need to modify that so that your values convert to the correct datatype correctly. e.g. you might have `F` in the field, and a direct conversion to boolean is not possible. So you would need to modify that block appropriately. :)